# Getting specific property and value with its selectors from CSS file

Tags: css, extract

Is there any automated way to get CSS property and value with its selectors from one giant CSS file? For example,

```
.selector1 {
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
.selector2 {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Now I want to extract CSS below from CSS above based on `#000` color value.

```
.selector1 {
    color: #000;
}
.selector2 {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Finding and editing manually in text editor works, but this approach is hard to accomplish after CSS is changed which is changed frequently. So I wonder if there is any automated way to do that.

Comment: Not really but you might want to look into CSS variables &/or those available with SASS/LESS....depending on your actual requirement. A **use-case** for the question would be useful so we can understand why this is required.

Comment: for test, you can load last an extra css file to override previous style

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is not possible with css but you can achieve it using JavaScript.

Comment: What kind of Javascript?